# Splitting string by number of characters matlab

Tags: string, matlab, octave

Is there any builtin function in Matlab that cuts string by the number of characters and returns it as a cell array or something. For example if call A = some_function(string, 3):

```
Input: string = '1234567890'
Output: A = {'123', '456', '789', '0'}
```

or do I need to use loops?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little long may be:

```
ns = numel(string);
n = 3;
A = cellstr(reshape([string repmat(' ',1,ceil(ns/n)*n-ns)],n,[])')'
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative solution, which is slightly more elegant (in my opinion), would be using [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html):

```
A = regexp(str, sprintf('\\w{1,%d}', n), 'match')
```

where `str` is your string and `n` is the number of characters.

#### Example

```
>> regexp('1234567890', '\w{1,3}', 'match')

ans = 
    '123'    '456'    '789'    '0'
```