# How to convert a character matrix into cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 64 characters in a 4*4 matrix.I need to convert it into a cell array such that cell has 4 characters.For eg

```
 Consider A=[TCTGCTCTCGGTTATATACACTGCCCAGAACACGTCAACAAGGCCAGTGTATCCTTCTTTGTGT]
```

i need to get a cell array as below

```
 B={[TCTG][CTCT][CGGT][TATA]
    [TACA][CTGC][CCAG][AACA]
    [CGTC][AACA][AGGC][CAGT]
    [GTAT][CCTT][CTTT][GTGT]}
```

i tried using the mat2cell function but im not able to understand it.please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691857/splitting-string-by-number-of-characters-matlab

Answer (score 2):

Using a for-loop:

```
clc
clear

A = 'TCTGCTCTCGGTTATATACACTGCCCAGAACACGTCAACAAGGCCAGTGTATCCTTCTTTGTGT';


B = cell(4,4);

currentIdx = 0; % Use index to increment by steps of 4 when going through A

for k = 1:16        
    B{k} = A(currentIdx+1:currentIdx+4);
    currentIdx = currentIdx+4;
end

B = B'

B = 

    'TCTG'    'CTCT'    'CGGT'    'TATA'
    'TACA'    'CTGC'    'CCAG'    'AACA'
    'CGTC'    'AACA'    'AGGC'    'CAGT'
    'GTAT'    'CCTT'    'CTTT'    'GTGT'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use method vec2mat that breaks your input vector to matrix

```
M = vec2mat(A, numberOfColumns)
```

(In your case numberOfColumns would be 16) and then use mat2cell. In your case, it would be:

```
C = mat2cell(M, [1,1,1,1], [4,4,4,4])
```

It means that all cels will have one row and 4 columns).

Effect of function c = mat2cell(x, [10, 20, 30], [25, 25]) would be:

[image: img]

The image shows why you have to convert vector to matrix. (example from matlab documentation)

Answer (score 2):

You are starting with a 1xN matrix and want to convert it to a 1xN/4 cell array of 1x4 matrices. Your command should then be:

```
N = length(A);
M = 4;
B = mat2cell(A,1,ones(1,N/M)*M);
```

The first dimension is the 1, the second dimension is a string of 4's the size of the output cell array. The result:

```
B = 

  Columns 1 through 12

    'TCTG'    'CTCT'    'CGGT'    'TATA'    'TACA'    'CTGC'    'CCAG'    'AACA'    'CGTC'    'AACA'    'AGGC'    'CAGT'

  Columns 13 through 16

    'GTAT'    'CCTT'    'CTTT'    'GTGT'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also (ab)use the very versatile [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) for this task:

```
A = 'TCTGCTCTCGGTTATATACACTGCCCAGAACACGTCAACAAGGCCAGTGTATCCTTCTTTGTGT';
n = 4;
B = accumarray(ceil(1/n:1/n:numel(A)/n).', A(:), [], @(x) {x.'}).'
```

Comment: thank u..Here does n indicate the number of strings or the size?

Comment: It's the size of each string. I chose 4 as in your example