# Generate new pairs based on a string

Tags: string, matlab

I have a string : str='HDEABGCF'. How can I create the new pairs which is from the second is combined with the third elements, the fourth with fifth , the sixth is combined with the seventh?

The expected output should be: result={'DE';'AB';'GC'}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting string by number of characters matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691857/splitting-string-by-number-of-characters-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abuse [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html), and ensuring you start from the second index of the string array going up to the second last index in increments of 2.  For each index, you'd access the string at the current index and the next index after that point, then ensure that the output is a cell array by using the `uni=0` flag:

```
>> str='HDEABGCF';
>> result = arrayfun(@(x) str([x x+1]), 2:2:numel(str)-1, 'uni', 0);
>> result

result = 

    'DE'    'AB'    'GC'
```